# Cannot get reference to my auto generated push IDs in android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an android app through android studio in java language. I have linked it to firebase Realtime database. There are auto generated push IDs as the last child. I want to retrieve my database values back in an activity. I am facing problem in giving reference to the push IDs.

This is what I have tried.

```
 myRef = myfire.getReference().child("Data").child(strUID).child("Traffic").child("Wedding");
        final String uid =myRef.getKey();
        myRef.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {


                    String stData1 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData1").getValue())).toString();
                    String stData2 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData2").getValue())).toString();
                    String stData3 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData3").getValue())).toString();
                    String stData4 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData4").getValue())).toString();


                    category basic = new category(stData1,stData2,stData3,stData4);
                    tvBalance.setText(stData4);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }



        });
```

Please provide a practical example.

**Edit**
This is my database structure:------------

```
Data>>
      user id>>>>
              Traffic>>>>

                   Wedding>>>>
                          Auto ID>>>
                                >stData1
                                >stData2
                                >stData3
                                >stData4 //I want to get this last value//
```

my json file

```
{
  "Data" : {
    "UyhzVqsz1BVFKoePa2NEmlPFu382" : {
      "Traffic" : {
        "Wedding" : {
          "-MYKeSN8GZ8WbI-8TfVB" : {
            "stData1" : "15 Apr 2021,06:43:00:pm",
            "stData2" : "Wedding",
            "stData3" : "kkk",
            "stData4" : "100"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to: 1) show your JSON fro the database (as text, no screenshots)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) Which part from that JSON you want to show in the activity?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for responding. I have done as instructed. What next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ways to get a node is by either knowing its full path, or by knowing the path to the parent node, and then some unique value under the node. Neither seems to be the case for the `stData4` in your JSON, so you'll have to load the entire `Wedding` node and then loop over the results to get the part you want.

This isn't too bad though:

```
myRef = myfire.getReference("Data").child(strUID).child("Traffic/Wedding");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String stData1 = childSnapshot.child("stData1").getValue(String.class);
                String stData2 = childSnapshot.child("stData2").getValue(String.class);
                String stData3 = childSnapshot.child("stData3").getValue(String.class);
                String stData4 = childSnapshot.child("stData4").getValue(String.class);
            }

            category basic = new category(stData1,stData2,stData3,stData4);
            tvBalance.setText(stData4);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

The code above assumes that:

- `strUID` has the value `UyhzVqsz1BVFKoePa2NEmlPFu382`

Comment: I got it. I should have used one level up.  Its the first time you answered  to my question. I hope the same in future. Thanks.